# Add Row in DataGridView ( with Predefined Columns)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

How to add a row in **datagridview in winform application**.

Scenario is:

- I've one **grid** on windows form.
- Grid's columns are pre-definded. (Here, I mean column index, name ,
  header text and    order is not changeable at runtime.)
- I need to add new row in that grid.

Anyone, help me in this regard. How can I do this task ?

Comment: datagridview.datasource= yourDataTabl;  Add new row into datatable and then bind again or add programaitcally to gridview

Comment: What about if you've no data source ? I mean, just want to add rows in grid and save them on application close or form close that contains grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try like this -

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(<col1 value>,<col2 value>,...)
```

The parameters will be values you intended for your each columns.

**EDIT :**

Taking your code from other comments, you can simply use it like this-

```
myMainApplication.dgvBooksDetails.Rows.Add(objBook.ID, objBook.Title, objBook.Author, 
            objBook.Genre, objBook.Price, objBook.PublishDate, objBook.Description);
```

**EDIT**

In Sub Form, store instance of Main Form -

```
public MainForm _mainForm;
```

In Main Form :

```
SubForm frm = new SubForm();
frm.MainForm = this;
frm.Show();
```

Then to fill up datagrid, do like this -

```
_mainForm.dgvBookDetails.Rows.Add(.....
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: col1 mean column name or id ?

Comment: its column value. if your column is of type `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and your value is "Hello World", the syntax would be `dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Hello World")...

Comment: Actually it depends on data gridview column type. You need to check all your datagrid column types and pass parameters in Add() function accordingly.

Comment: All the columns are textboxes. So, what to do next ?

Comment: Well, I come to conclusion and it is that: if I code in main application then it add rows. But if I open sub form and set values of row and add. It doesn't update grid on main form. Do you've any idea about this matter ?

Comment: How do you access the datagridview of main form in sub form?? Can you plz update your answer and post your code?

Comment: main form controls are accesible by creating object of that form in sub form and those control which need to be accessed are having public access specifier. So, in access there is no issue.

Comment: Thats where the problem is... You are creating a new instance of the main form and adding rows to its datagridview. Actually you have to pass a reference of the same main form to the sub form and then add rows to datagridview of that instance...

Comment: Thank you so much for help. It works for me, but with slight change. And change is that I create static instance of main form and then use it for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, add the row in your datatable and bind the source with your datagridview like this:

```
row = dtTable.NewRow();
///HereEnter the value in row
dtTable.Rows.Add(row);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtTable;
```

If you want to add row without using datasoruce, then you have to use [DataGridViewRowCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbs04kbx.aspx) method.:

Answer (score 0):

Add newrow in your datatable and bind it as i mentioned in my above comments
 or do this way

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get all rows entered on each press of Enter.
            var collection = this.dataGridView1.Rows;
            string output = "";
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in collection)
            {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Value != null)
                {
                output += cell.Value.ToString() + " ";
                }
            }
            }
            // Display.
            this.Text = output;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1)` do the trick for you ?

It should add a row corresponding to `RowTemplate` of the `DataGridView`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DataTable object as the datasource for your DatagGridView then i suggest you use a binding source.

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

bs.DataSource = DataTable;

DataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Now add rows to the Data Table as mentioned previously.

Using this method, any changes that are made to the Data Table are automatically reflected in your GridView.